# Переход в активити после нажатия двух кнопок

Tags: java, android-studio

Android Studio.Java
Никак не могу сделать переход в другое активити. Мне нужно чтобы, когда были нажаты две ImageButton переходило в другое активити.
Например как в игрушках, где ты ищешь предметы и как только ты собрал всё, переходишь на другой уровень.

Answer (score 1):

внутри onCreate поставьте этот код и измените названия кнопки на ваше

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (preferences.getBoolean("button2", false)){
                editor.remove("button2");
                startActivity(new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class));
            }else {
                editor.putBoolean("button1", true);
            }
        }
    });

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (preferences.getBoolean("button1", false)){
                editor.remove("button1");
                startActivity(new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class));
            }else {
                editor.putBoolean("button2", true);
            }
        }
    });
```